# Is a subgroup of a topological group a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I'm trying to solve the problem from Munkres: Let $H$ be a subspace of $G$. (Where $G$ is a topological group). Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then both H and H closure are topological groups.

Is it enough to say that the maps $H\times H \rightarrow H$ sending $x \times y$ to $xy$ and $x \rightarrow x^{-1}$ are continuous as restrictions of the corresponding functions on $G$ as a topological group? And similarly for $H$ closure?

Comment: That may be fine for $H$, but the "problem" with $\overline H$ is rather to show that it is a group

Comment: Okay, but for the continuous functions part my argument is valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$F \subseteq G$ is a subgroup of G if and only if $a,b \in F$ $\implies$ $ab^{-1}$ is an element of F.

Another way to see this is to prove that the function $f(x,y) = x*y^{-1}$ applied to F is a subset of F.

So we want to show that $f(\overline H×\overline H)$ $\subseteq\overline H$.

We then simply observe f$(\overline H×\overline H)$ $=$ $f(\overline{H \times H})$ $\subseteq \overline {f(H \times H)} \subseteq \overline H$.

Thus $\overline H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and its corresponding multiplication and inversion maps are continuous as restrictions of the corresponding maps of $G$. So $\overline H$ is a topological group.

Answer (score 8):

If $H\le G$ (*$H$ is a subgroup of $G$*), then the restriction of $*:G\times G\to G$ to $H×H$ is continuous, being the restriction of a continuous map to a subspace (A subtlety which should be appreciated here is  that $H×H$ with the product topology is the same as $H×H⊆G×G$ with the subspace topology. **Edit:** I just realized you only need continuity of $H \times H \to G \times G$, the product of the inclusion $H \to G$ with itself, in order to deduce that $H \times H \to H$ is continuous). The same holds for $()^{-1}:H\to H$.

For the $\overline H$ you need to show that this closure is still a subgroup, i.e. that multiplication of two elements in $\overline H$ does not lead outside of $\overline H$. In other words, show that $*\left(\overline H×\overline H\right)\subseteq\overline H$. The equality $\overline H×\overline H=\overline{H×H}$ may be useful here.

Comment: Thanks very much! I see it now.

Comment: How do we show that this is a topology generated by subspace topology? Do we need to consider $U$ a open subset of $G$ and consider $U \cap H$ and show finite intersection and arbitrary union properties?

Comment: Are you asking how we show that the product topology on $H\times H$ is the same as the subspace topology from $G\times G$? @Sayantani

Comment: @Sayantani: You need to be more specific about which step of my proof you have problems with. Is it about why $*: H \times H \to H$ is continuous? This map is continuous because the composition $H \times H \stackrel*\to H \to G$ is continuous, the latter map being the inclusion of $H$ into $G$. The reason for this is that we can write the composition as $H \times H \to G \times G \stackrel*\to G$, where the first map is the square of the inclusion of $H$ into $G$.

Comment: How to show when $H$ becomes a topo space in itself, it gets the subspace topology generated on $H$ as a subspace of $G$ ? Do we need to find the open sets of the subspace topology as $U \cap H$ where $U$ is open in $G$ and show that those are included in topology generated on $H$, and vice versa? I hope I could make it clear.

Comment: @noob: The subgroup $H$ has the subspace topology induced from $G$ because that is the topology we decide to equip $H$ with. There is no other topology on $H$ that is somehow generated by its group structure. The point here is rather to show that, now that $H$ inherits its topology from $G$, this topology makes the multiplication $H \times H \to H$ continuous.

Answer (score 0):

In general, closed subgroups of a topological group are topological group*. Although  the maps $p:H\times H\longrightarrow G$  and $i:H\longrightarrow G$ are continuos, this not implies in general that $p:H\times H\longrightarrow H$ and $i:H\longrightarrow H$ are  continuos.

In order to proof the clain *, we will use the following characterization of continuos function: $f:X\longrightarrow Y $ is continuous if, and only if, $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$ for all subset $A$ of $X$ (Munkres, page 104). Let $A\subset H\times H$. Then, as $H\times H$ is closed in $G\times G$, the clousure of $A$ in $H\times H$ is the same as the clousure of  $A$ in $G\times G$. As $p:G\times G\longrightarrow G$ is continuos, we have that $p(\overline{A}^{H\times H})=p(\overline{A}^{G\times G})\subset\overline{p(A)}^G=\overline{p(A)}^H$, concluiding that the product operation of $H$ is continuos. As the inversion $i:G\longrightarrow G$ is continuos, we have $i(\overline A^H)=i(\overline{A}^G)\subset \overline{i(A)}^G=\overline{i(A)}^H$, concluiding that the inversion operation of $H$ is continuos. Therefore, $H$ is a topological group (here, $\overline{A}^X$ denote the closure of $A$ in $X$. Note that if $A$ and $B$ are two closed subsets of $X$ and $A\subset B$, then $A$ is closed in $B$, since that $B-A=(X-A)\cap B$).